# Accept single value as array using Micronaut Serialization

Tags: java, deserialization, micronaut

I'm consuming a 3rd party API that returns either an array of objects or a single object if there is only one object returned. This causes an error when trying to decode the JSON into my POJO class, with `Unexpected token START_OBJECT, expected START_ARRAY`.

With Jackson-Databind, there is a config option to accept single values as arrays (
`@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)`), but this does not seem to be supported by Micronaut Serialization.

Is there any way of working around having to write a custom deserialization class for this?

---

Example Pojo class:

```
@Serdeable.Deserializable
public class Reponse {
   private List<Package> package;
}
```

Example API response with single object:

```
{
  "package": [
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

vs single object:

```
{
  "package": 
    {}
}
```

When the API returns a single object, this results in the following error:

```
DEBUG io.micronaut.http.client.jdk.HttpResponseAdapter Error decoding body for type [...] from 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'. Attempting fallback.
DEBUG io.micronaut.http.client.jdk.HttpResponseAdapter CodecException Message was: Error decoding stream for type [class ...]: Error decoding property [...] of type [class ...]: Error decoding property [List ...] of type [class ...]: Error decoding property [List ...] of type [class ...]: Unexpected token START_OBJECT, expected START_ARRAY  at [Source: (byte[]) ..."
```